# STM8S I2C Master Missing ACK

Tags: communication, i2c, stm8

I use I2C communication with two stm8s boards.

My master code:

```
I2C_GenerateSTART(ENABLE);
I2C_Send7bitAddress(0x30, I2C_DIRECTION_TX);
I2C_SendData(0x61);
I2C_GenerateSTOP(ENABLE);
delay(1500);
```

My slave address is 0x30. I send 0x61.
I analyzed stm8s master board with ossiloscope. I see from lister:

Address:30R

Data: anything

Missing ACK: X(with red background)

My signal from master board with stm8s:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

what could be the problem for missing ack? And, is it true address and data values? Thank you!

And,

My master arduino code:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x30); // transmit to device 0x30
Wire.write(0x61);              // sends one byte
Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
delay(500);
```

And this picture from master arduino code with ossiloscope:
[image]

Here, adress is 30W, but adress of my stm8s master code is 30R.
I changed this line of the stm8s master code:

```
I2C_Send7bitAddress(0x30, I2C_DIRECTION_RX); 
//I2C_Send7bitAddress(0x30, I2C_DIRECTION_TX);
```

But adress is still 30R.

code of this line:

```
/**
  * @brief  Transmits the 7-bit address (to select the) slave device.
  * @param   Address : Specifies the slave address which will be transmitted.
  * @param   Direction : Specifies whether the I2C device will be a Transmitter or a Receiver.
  * This parameter can be any of the @ref I2C_Direction_TypeDef enumeration.
  * @retval None
  */
void I2C_Send7bitAddress(uint8_t Address, I2C_Direction_TypeDef Direction)
{
  /* Check function parameters */
  assert_param(IS_I2C_ADDRESS_OK(Address));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_DIRECTION_OK(Direction));

  /* Clear bit0 (direction) just in case */
  Address &= (uint8_t)0xFE;

  /* Send the Address + Direction */
  I2C->DR = (uint8_t)(Address | (uint8_t)Direction);
}
```

and

```
/**
  * @brief  I2C transfer direction
  * Warning: the values correspond to the ADD0 bit position in the OARL register
  */
typedef enum
{
  I2C_DIRECTION_TX = (uint8_t)0x00,  /*!< Transmission direction */
  I2C_DIRECTION_RX = (uint8_t)0x01   /*!< Reception direction */
} I2C_Direction_TypeDef;
```

/**************************NOW*******************************************/
I changed my stm8s I2C master code:

```
I2C_GenerateSTART(ENABLE);
I2C_Send7bitAddress(0x30, I2C_DIRECTION_TX);
I2C_SendData(0x60); //I have no idea, i tried it and works for write/read selection
I2C_SendData(0x61); //my send data
I2C_GenerateSTOP(ENABLE);
delay_delay(1500);
```

Adress is 30W, now. It is true because i want to write to slave. Then, I saw this signal from ossiloscope:

[image]

This signal is same with Arduino master transmitter.

But, I can't see signal of the data. What could be the reason for this? Missing ACK or another thing? I don't know, but data signal is no of the arduino signal. Missing ACK?

Thank you!

Comment: Your slave is supposed to be sending the ACK back to your master. Have you enabled that in your slave code?

Comment: We'd need to see your slave code to know more. Your master code says I2C_DIRECTION_TX but the bus shows a read, not a write. The eighth bit of the transfer should be a 0 for TX. Also, I'm not sure you need to send a stop condition after an address NACK.

Comment: I edited my post for your comment. @AdamHaun

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard formats for 7-bit I2C addresses -- 0x7F and 0xFE. It looks like I2C_Send7bitAddress() expects 0xFE format. If your actual slave address is 0x30, try sending 0x60 (which is 0x30 << 1) and see if that works.

The reason for the 0xFE format is that it lets you treat the read/write direction bit as part of the slave address, giving an 8-bit value. That's what you actually see on the bus.

Comment: Ok, i tried with online c compiler, but 0xC0 << 1 is: http://goo.gl/XfbymG

Comment: Oops! It's not 0xC0, it's 0x60. You left-shift the address (0x30) by one to convert to 0xFE form, which gives you 0x60.

Comment: Hello @AdamHaun, I can change write/read selection. Address(0x30) and data direction(write) are true, now. But, I can't see signal of the data. What could be the reason for this? Missing ACK or another thing? I don't know, but data signal is no of the arduino signal. Missing ACK?

Thank you!

Comment: It's almost certainly the missing ACK. The problem is probably on the slave side.